# Can't modify user permissions on a folder

Tags: windows, permissions

I am trying to give another user write access to a network folder on Windows. When I try to make any changes to the folder permissions, I get an error message:

```
An error occurred while applying security information to:

\\computer\path\to\folder

Access is denied.
```

Everything I have found suggests taking ownership of the folder, but I am already the owner and the "Effective Permissions" dialog box says I have full control.

What else could be preventing me from making any changes to the permissions settings?

Comment: Ok, so you have ownership and permissions on the NTFS level. Do you also have write rights the to share it is on?

Comment: @Hennes: Yes. The effective permissions for the network share says I have full control. I am not the owner of the share, though. Just the folder.

Comment: Just making sure. I've been bitten before by the cumulative effects of share permissions and NTFS filesystem permissions. And judging from my coworkers I was not the only one.

Comment: try this solution here http://superuser.com/questions/210993/lack-of-permission-to-open-user-folder