# Access User X private data as adminstrator

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, administrator, my-documents

My girlfriends Laptop died a few days ago, now I'm on it to rescue her data. So I put her HDD as slave on my WIN 8 pc. Now is the problem she has all her needed data in her users folder. How may I access it? I already tried via "as Admistrator" but didn't work. If it is important, she had a WIN 7 OS.

Comment: You could try a rescue disc, either Windows-based, such as _Hiren's Boot CD_ (http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd), or Linux-based, such as _Knoppix_ (http://www.knoppix.org) or Ubuntu Live CD.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Grant access to User folder on external drive](http://superuser.com/questions/697329/grant-access-to-user-folder-on-external-drive), and/or [Lack of permission to open user folder](http://superuser.com/questions/210993/lack-of-permission-to-open-user-folder)

Comment: Sorry for that, we may delete this question then, after 3 upvotes of this comment I will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't been there myself, but I would take ownership of her user folder, alternatively using the program Unlocker in the proces. Have you tried to copy the folder to your own desktop, and go at it from there?

Comment: Cant take the ownership, will try to copy

Comment: Copy works... and again, thank you windows for your great security.....